How to color Multicolumn and Multirow correctly
i am new to LaTeX and i need to create a specific Table. It is important that the top topics in the left column are coloured grey. Because these are cells that consist of several rows, it is difficult for me to colour the whole thing correctly.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Für farbige Zellen
\usepackage{colortbl} % Für das Färben von Zellen in Tabellen
\usepackage{float} % Für die genaue Platzierung der Tabelle im Text
\usepackage{graphicx} % Falls du Grafiken einbinden möchtest
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% setting local to this center environment
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BFBFBF}\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Generation}}} & Faithfulness & \cellcolor{white}0.9639 \\
& Answer Relevancy & \cellcolor{white}0.8648 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Retrieval}}} & Context Recall & \cellcolor{white}0.9583 \\
& Context Precision & \cellcolor{white}1.0000 \\
& Context Relevancy & \cellcolor{white}0.8677 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{End-to-end}}} & Answer Correctness & \cellcolor{white}0.8351 \\
& Answer Semantic Similarity & \cellcolor{white}0.9250 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document} 


Welcome. // Please review the code you posted and remove all packages that don't contribute to show your attempt: it may be much less than 5 packages needed here. If in doubt, comment some out and compile. Continue until you know which ones are vital and which are not.

Like this?
Since your document class isn't on CTAN, I used article.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{BFBFBF}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={clc},
  vlines,stretch=0,
  hline{1,3,6,Z}={solid},
  column{1}={mygray, font=\bfseries},
  }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}Generation & Faithfulness & 0.9639 \\
& Answer Relevancy & 0.8648 \\ 
\SetCell[r=3]{c}Retrieval & Context Recall & 0.9583 \\
& Context Precision & 1.0000 \\
& Context Relevancy & 0.8677 \\ 
\SetCell[r=2]{c}End-to-end & Answer Correctness & 0.8351 \\
& Answer Semantic Similarity & 0.9250 \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{BFBFBF}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\columncolor{mygray}\bfseries}clc}[vlines]
\Hline
\Block{2-1}{Generation} & Faithfulness               & 0.9639 \\
                        & Answer Relevancy           & 0.8648 \\ 
\Hline
\Block{3-1}{Retrieval}  & Context Recall             & 0.9583 \\
                        & Context Precision          & 1.0000 \\
                        & Context Relevancy          & 0.8677 \\ 
\Hline
\Block{2-1}{End-to-end} & Answer Correctness         & 0.8351 \\
                        & Answer Semantic Similarity & 0.9250 \\ 
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}


